# Is a class level variable a good idea for ths situation?

Tags: c++, oop

I have some situations where I have the following:

The class receives a message from the server with a value. I then send the server back another message. I store the value received in a class level variable, `ex : m_number = server->args[0];`

I then later get a message again from the server and this time I execute a method in the class that needs the stored variable from earlier and some new variables from the server.

Is it a good idea to have a variable just for this purpose?

Another example is I get a variable from the server, then another system needs the information I got from the server which is why I need to store it because I do not know when the other system will want it, just that it will want it some time after I receive it.

Thanks

Comment: Your approach is perfectly fine. That's what variables are for. :)

Comment: What else would you use?

Comment: It's important that you clarify if you mean instance variable, or static (class) variable?  I assumed you meant static, but it's not clear from your question (just see that most responses interpreted instance var)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit: I've answered on the assumption that by "class-level variable", you mean a `static` data member of a class. Two other people have answered assuming that you mean a non-static data member of a class. Please ignore the answer(s) that are irrelevant to you :-)]

It's probably not a great idea. Suppose that somewhere down the line, you want to talk to two different servers at once. Now you have two different values that you need to store in the same static data member.

Better would be to have some object that represents your connection/conversation/session with a particular server, and to store any state relating to that server in there.

That said, not all software needs great ideas in order to work, so you might get away with it. Just bear in mind that morally it's a global, and globals often lead to trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It's an excellent idea in this situation. Generally, that's what you need member variables for.

Answer (score 0):

Well why not? This is actually the whole purpose of variables is it not? If you didn't have to remember anything, then you wouldn't be using a class with "states" rather, a function. From the description in your question it seems you have a class with more than one states so you need some kind of mechanism to remember that. So yes I think it's perfectly fine.